# Exibir filhos (children) apenas ao clicar no term pai

Tags: wordpress, submenu, taxonomia

Tenho uma *sidebar* e preciso listar os termos da taxonomia 'Categoria'.

Até aí tudo bem, o que não consigo fazer é: Ao clicar em um termo, deve listar o termos filhos dele em um submenu contendo um link para a listagem dos produto dessa de filho.

Código atual

sidebar.php

```
<aside class="sidebar col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="caterias-sidebar">
        <p class="titulo-cat">CATEGORIA</p>
        <?php print_produtos_por_tax('Categoria'); ?>
    </div>
</aside>
```

ATUALIZADA 1.1 -> functions.php

```
function print_produtos_por_tax($termos){

 $taxonomyName = $termos;
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
echo '<ul>';
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<ul><li><a class="elementos-cat" href="#'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
    echo '<li><ul class="ul-submenu">';
    foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
        $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
        echo '<li id="#'.$term->term_id.'" class="elementos-cat li-submenu" ><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}




jQuery(".elementos-cat").click(function () {
    jQuery(".ul-submenu").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Atualmente não está identificando qual Pai foi clicado para mostrar apenas os filhos dele.

Deve funcionar assim: Ao clicar em Compressor, deve listar todas imagens de produtos independente da subcategoria do Compressor, mas deve abrir um submenu de Compressor contendo a lista (Compressor tipo 1, Compressor tipo 2, Compressor tipo 3…)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Site: `http://104.131.64.90`

Comment: Não use o *snippet* de Javascript para formatar código  em PHP. E veja também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo

Comment: Deixe-me ver se entendi. Nessa pagina por exemplo: "http://104.131.64.90/categoria/compressor/" a sidebar teria que mostrar os "filhos" dos compressores?

Comment: Vou deixar aqui uma dica para quem não conhece sobre o assunto. Pelo trecho do seu código parece que você está fazendo uma função para cada coisa do seu site. Tome cuidado! Um site desse tem varias paginas com diferentes funções. Para isso use Orientação a Objetos, assim você cria um código consistente e humano. Links: [Introdução a OOP - DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-orientacao-a-objetos-em-php/26762) e [Um pouco sobre classes - SlideShare](http://pt.slideshare.net/jonyw4/classes-40332577)

Comment: Por favor, publique a solução em forma de resposta. E se explicar o que fez para solucionar vai ajudar a quem procurar pela mesma coisa e vier parar aqui.

Comment: Se quiser publicar sua resposta em seu nome, me avise e deleto a minha que coloquei em modo wiki. O site é de Perguntas & Respostas, soluções não devem ser publicadas dentro da pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

```
function print_produtos_e_filhos( $tax_name ) {
    $cats = get_terms( $tax_name, [ 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => true ] );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
        if ( ! $cat->slug != 'destaque' ) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <span class="elementos-cat li-span">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat ); ?>">
                        <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="ver-filhos">\/</span>
                <?php render_children( $cat ); ?>
            </li>

        <?php
        }
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
}

function render_children( $parent ) {
    $children = get_terms( $parent->taxonomy, [ 'parent' => $parent->term_id, 'hide_empty' => true ] );
    echo '<ul class="ul-submenu">';
    foreach ( $children as $kid ):
        ?>
        <li class="elementos-cat li-submenu">
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $kid ); ?>">
                <?php echo $kid->name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(".ver-filhos").click(function () {
    jQuery('.ul-submenu', jQuery(this).parent()).slideToggle('fast', function () {
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('ul-menu-ativo');
    });
    return false;

});
```